# LINQ how to merge two columns in one column of query result

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Hi the datebase schema is something look like this :

[image]

and please take look at query below (I want to get inventory of a player 5000 for game with gameID 1001) :

```
 var gameID=1001;
 var playerID=5000;
 var q = from p in Players
        join gp in GamePlays on p.PlayerID equals gp.PlayerID
        join gpi in GamePlayItems on gp.GamePlayID equals gpi.GamePlayID        
        join it in Items on gpi.ItemID equals it.ItemID
        where p.PlayerID == playerID
        where it.GameID == gameID

select new 
{
    GamePlayID = gp.GamePlayID,
    ItemName = it.ItemName,
    ItemValue = gpi.ItemValue,
};
q.Dump();
```

the result is depicted below:

[image]

but I don't want that the column GamePlayID to be repeated . I want just get only record which the second column  is hash set or a list contains Inventories.(I want to merge column two and three in one column). how can achieve this? for example my desire result is :

```
GamePlayID       Items
---------        -----
6                A List => { (ItemName1, ItemValue1), ....}
```

**UPDATE  :**

by ruuning Gilad Green Query the result is something look like this :
query :

```
var q = (from p in db.Players
             join gp in db.GamePlays on p.PlayerID equals gp.PlayerID
             join gpi in db.GamePlayItems on gp.GamePlayID equals gpi.GamePlayID
             join it in db.Items on gpi.ItemID equals it.ItemID
             where p.PlayerID == playerID
             where it.GameID == gameID
             group new
             {
                 ItemName = it.ItemName,
                 ItemValue = gpi.ItemValue
             }
             by new
             {
                 gp.GamePlayID,
                 gp.BestTimeRecord,
                 gp.PlayedNumber,
                 gp.ScoreNumber,
                 gp.WinNumber
             }

             into groups
             select new { Statictics = groups.Key, Items = groups }).ToList();
```

[image]

but i don't want have key in items...
why this occurs?

**UPDATE  2 :**

**both answers of Ivan Stoev , Gilad Green  are correct...**

Comment: Group by GamePlayID?

Comment: @J.Steen : can you help for accomplish this..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query for the `group by`:

```
from p in Players
join gp in GamePlays on p.PlayerID equals gp.PlayerID
join gpi in GamePlayItems on gp.GamePlayID equals gpi.GamePlayID
join it in Items on gpi.ItemID equals it.ItemID
where p.PlayerID == playerID
where it.GameID == gameID

group new 
{ 
    ItemName = it.ItemName, 
    ItemValue = gpi.ItemValue 
} 
by new 
{
    GamePlayID = gp.GamePlayID
    //Here you add other keys you want
} into groups

select new { GamePlayID = groups.Key.GamePlayID, Items = groups.ToList() };
```

Comment: thanks it is very nice but how can I add multiple keys , can I use by new {...}

Comment: @S.A.Parkhid - Check now. Added a `.ToList()` when assigning `groups` to `Items`

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to group by, you can simply turn the join to `(GamePlayItems, Items)` part into a [group join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx#Anchor_1) like this:

```
var q =
    from p in Players
    where p.PlayerID == playerID
    join gp in GamePlays on p.PlayerID equals gp.PlayerID
    join x in (
        from gpi in GamePlayItems        
        join it in Items on gpi.ItemID equals it.ItemID
        where it.GameID == gameID
        select new { gpi, it })
    on gp.GamePlayID equals x.gpi.GamePlayID into items
    select new 
    {
        GamePlayID = gp.GamePlayID,
        Items = items.Select(x => new { ItemName = x.it.ItemName, ItemValue = x.gpi.ItemValue }).ToList(),
    };
```

Comment: this is nice but if player have more than one GamePlays ,query above will return all of them but with no inventroies.

Comment: In my understanding, the `GamePlayID` is a PK in `GamePlays`, so the data is already "naturally" grouped by `GamePlayID`. If you mean that group join returns records even if there are not related sub records, that's true, the group join has a left outer join semantics. Adding `where items.Any()` before the `select` clause will eliminate that case. In general I avoid grouping by PK in my queries, for yours - it's up to you :)

Comment: Ya it is true and your query is nice but i had accepted answer before!

Comment: No problem mate, just responding to your comment.